# csscript unloading assembly used with an interface

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute cs scripts in a directory a loop. Every time the script changed (or if it's new) it gets loaded and executed. But I receive an error on trying to load the script a second time:

`Access to the path 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\CSSCRIPT\Cache\647885655\hello.cs.compiled' is denied.`

What I tried to do was:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> mFilePathFileHashes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public static void LoadFromDir(string dir)
{
    foreach (string filepath in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
    {
        string hash = GetMD5HashFromFile(filepath); //Generate file hash
        if (mFilePathFileHashes.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(filepath, hash))) continue; //Skip if it hasn't changed

        if (mFilePathFileHashes.ContainsKey(filepath))
        { //Hash changed
            mFilePathFileHashes[filepath] = hash;
        }
        else //This is the first time this file entered the loop
            mFilePathFileHashes.Add(filepath, hash);

        //Load the script
        IScript script = CSScript.Load(filepath)
                            .CreateInstance("Script")
                            .AlignToInterface<IScript>();

        //Do stuff
        script.AddUserControl();
    }

protected static string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
    file.Close();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

At the "Load the script" part it would throw the error. So I [read up](http://www.csscript.net/help/Script_hosting_guideline_.html) on it a bit and tried this:

```
//Load the script
string asmFile = CSScript.Compile(filepath, null, false);
using (AsmHelper helper = new AsmHelper(asmFile, "temp_dom_" + Path.GetFileName(filepath), true))
{
    IScript script = helper.CreateAndAlignToInterface<IScript>("Script");
    script.AddUserControl();

    //helper.Invoke("Script.AddUserControl");
}
```

Because that page said `Script is loaded in the temporary AppDomain and unloaded after the execution. To set up the AsmHelper to work in this mode instantiate it with the constructor that takes the assembly file name as a parameter`

But that won't Align to the interface : `Type 'Script' in Assembly 'hello.cs, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.` What does that even mean, and why would it need to be serializable?

If I switch to the `helper.Invoke` line instead I get a NullReferenceException.

The script:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CSScriptTest;

class Script : CSScriptTest.IScript
{ 
    public void AddUserControl()
    {
        Form1.frm.AddUserControl1(this, "test_uc_1");
    }
}
```

So that last error may be because I never actually Aligned to an interface, or because I am calling a static method from outside of the main AppDomain (I really wouldn't know).

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: Your IScript is surely the problem.  Make sure that interface type is declared in *another* assembly, one you can afford to get loaded into your primary appdomain.

Comment: The interface itself is declared in the main program.. how could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works by passing the object I want to operate on to the interface' method like this:

```
using (var helper = new AsmHelper(CSScript.Compile(filepath), null, false))
{
    IScript script = helper.CreateAndAlignToInterface<IScript>("Script");
    script.AddUserControl(Form1.frm);
}
```

With the script inheriting from `MarshalByRefObject` like so:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CSScriptTest;

class Script : MarshalByRefObject, CSScriptTest.IScript
{ 
    public void AddUserControl(CSScriptTest.Form1 host)
    {
        host.AddUserControl1(this, "lol2");
    }
}
```

MSDN sais `MarshalByRefObject Enables access to objects across application domain boundaries in applications that support remoting.` So I guess that makes sense.. but is there any way for me to expose my main application's methods to the scripts?

It doesn't seem to be possible by inheriting from `MarshalByRefObject` in the main program, like so:

```
public class CTestIt : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public static CTestIt Singleton;
    internal static void SetSingleton()
    { //This method is successfully executed before we start loading scripts
        Singleton = new CTestIt();
        Console.WriteLine("CTestIt Singleton set"); 
    }

    public static void test()
    {
       //Null reference when a script calls CSScriptTest.CTestIt.test();
        Singleton.test_member(); 
    }

    public void test_member()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```